# TSQL - Error in stored procedure due to conversion failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this situation in a stored Procedure:

```
SET @DATE_RELEASE_START = '2015-01-01';
SET @DATE_RELEASE_END = '2015-05-31'

    SELECT @statement = ' SELECT * 
                          FROM (SELECT AFCDENTE, M.ID_MODIFICATION_CODE, COUNT(*) AS Conteggio--, CAST((COUNT(*)  * 100/ 15032) AS decimal(10,7)) AS Percentage
                                FROM CIC_LOG_MODIFICHE AS L INNER JOIN ADM_MODIFICATION_CODE AS M ON L.CD_MODIFICATION_CODE = M.CD_MODIFICATION_CODE
                                                            INNER JOIN CIC_PRODUZIONE AS P ON P.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE = L.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE
                                WHERE AFDTMODI BETWEEN '+@DATE_RELEASE_START+' AND '+@DATE_RELEASE_END+' AND P.CD_PLANT = '+@CD_PLANT+' AND AFCDENTE IS NOT NULL
                                GROUP BY AFCDENTE, M.ID_MODIFICATION_CODE) as tbl 
                        PIVOT (SUM(tbl.Conteggio) for tbl.ID_MODIFICATION_CODE in (' + @columns + ')) as pvt'
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I tried casting those dates but no changes. I get the same error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it like that:

```
SET @DATE_RELEASE_START = '2015-01-01';
SET @DATE_RELEASE_END = '2015-05-31'

    SELECT @statement = ' SELECT * 
                          FROM (SELECT AFCDENTE, M.ID_MODIFICATION_CODE, COUNT(*) AS Conteggio--, CAST((COUNT(*)  * 100/ 15032) AS decimal(10,7)) AS Percentage
                                FROM CIC_LOG_MODIFICHE AS L INNER JOIN ADM_MODIFICATION_CODE AS M ON L.CD_MODIFICATION_CODE = M.CD_MODIFICATION_CODE
                                                            INNER JOIN CIC_PRODUZIONE AS P ON P.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE = L.CD_CIC_PRODUZIONE
                                WHERE AFDTMODI BETWEEN @p0 AND @p1 AND P.CD_PLANT = @p2 AND AFCDENTE IS NOT NULL
                                GROUP BY AFCDENTE, M.ID_MODIFICATION_CODE) as tbl 
                        PIVOT (SUM(tbl.Conteggio) for tbl.ID_MODIFICATION_CODE in (' + @columns + ')) as pvt'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement, N'@p0 DATETIME2, @p1 DATETIME2, @p0 NVARCHAR(1000)', @p0 = @DATE_RELEASE_START, @p1 = @DATE_RELEASE_END, @p2 = @CD_PLANT;
```

Instead casting them as VARCHAR, just pass them as variables and then use `sp_executesql` to do the right job.

Comment: Ooops! You need to use `YYYYMMDD` if the type is `datetime` or pass a time component as well. `YYYY-MM-DD` works for the `date` type

Comment: I'm using `DATETIME2` and according to documentation `YYYY-MM-DD` is supported. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Not quite. You are looking either at the `date` formats or didn't notice that `datetime2` formats also include a time component. `yyyy-MM-dd` will be parsed like any other string and possibly result in issues eg with US dates. It's best to use an unambiguous format like `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well that's awkward. Never faced that issue, but if you're telling, I'll believe it. So the suggestion would be replacing `DATETIME2` with `DATE`, that's it?

Comment: Hm, wouldn't it be better to use the yyyyMMdd format for date-only strings instead of changing the column type?

Answer (score 2):

You must quote the date strings in your SQL code properly:

```
WHERE AFDTMODI BETWEEN '''+@DATE_RELEASE_START+''' AND '''+@DATE_RELEASE_END+'''
```

Otherwise the SQL will read

```
WHERE AFDTMODI BETWEEN 2015-01-01 AND 2015-05-31
```

instead of

```
WHERE AFDTMODI BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-05-31'
```

---

We've also had problems before with passing date/time values to stored procedures in Management Studio. We needed to give the date as `20150101` or `20150531`.

Comment: How did you pass them? There is no ambiguity in `declare @start date ='2015-12-31', this will create a `date`-typed variable with the correct date. Did you mix dates with datetimes? In this case you have to either specify a full ISO datetime or use the `YYYYMMDD`format

Comment: Just *don't* use string concatenation though and you won't have any problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We almost always use `DateTime` values and ran into this problem. About string concatenation: +1 for that.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar that's because `yyyy-MM-dd` isn't the ISO datetime format, there is no time component. `date` though has no time component and `yyyy-MM-dd` *is* the ISO format. The weird thing though is that `yyyyMMdd` *doesn't` work for `date`!